# Jquery MixItUp - Issue with hidden divs

Tags: jquery, html, mixitup

I'm having an issue with Jquery MixitUp and hidden divs. The idea is click one one button and show up one div with filters and thumbnails.

When i change the display of the main content, the mixitUp doesn't work. If i have the main content with display block, the script works well.

Here the both examples:

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yrjsr6bp/ - Fiddle working
http://jsfiddle.net/yrjsr6bp/1/ - Fiddle not working

```
<a onclick="$('#div5').show();" style='color:#000;'>SHOW THE DIV</a>
```

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**
I found the solution. The solutions is to run the script of mixitup in the same function where i change the display of the div. Thanks!

Comment: It's good you have provided examples but I think you would have a higher chance of getting answers if you provided a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead.

Comment: Works for me.when I click show the div it shows it. then I click the press or articles it changes the url the same way in both.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

You should initialize mixitup when the div is visible, you can easily do like so:

```
onclick="$('#div5').show(); $('#presscontainer').mixItUp();"
```

---

Better yet, abstract the javascript from the html:

HTML

```
<a id="showDivLink" style='color:#000;'>SHOW THE DIV</a>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#showDivLink').click(function (e) {
        $('#div5').show().promise().done(function () {
            $('#presscontainer').mixItUp();
        });
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/yrjsr6bp/2/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. The problem is not the name of the function, with other name i have the same issue. I think it's something with the display of the div because it's the only difference between both examples.